# decompose text into multi-class

Tags: deep-learning, classification, seq2seq

am looking for a machine learning algorithm which serves as String decoder (Multi-label classifier).
for example , decompose an email `xyz@qwe.abc.com` into different classes with/out probability

```
xyz:owner
@:special_character
qwe:sub-domain
abc.domain
```

or 231115

```
23:hour
11:minute
15:seconds
```

my case is more complex, but the above would guide me where to look.
for example I might have
 `74als353d`
    74:family
    als:ftype
    353d:id
and

```
73das
7:family
as:ftype
3d:id
```

I came across deep learning alogirthm  `SEQ2SEQ` would be a good starting point ?

Comment: Can you add more information about your problem? For now I would say that you only need regex.

Comment: i have provided an example, the text I have doesn't have specific section count and might or might not be ordered. what am l was expecting to do is .. for example provide a feature_value and the algorithm provide label probability but I guess on characters level, not words